# Assert.fail() stops all tests on runTestOnUiThread()

Tags: android, testing, junit, instrumentation

I have the following problem. I'm using `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` to make a few tests on my Android App. The code is the following:

```
public class LoginTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LoginActivity> {
  final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws IOException, JSONException {
    repository = getActivity().getRestAdapter().instance();
  }

  @SmallTest
  public void testNullCredentials() throws InterruptedException{
    runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        repository.loginUser(username, password, new LoginCallback() {

          @Override
          public void onSuccess(AccessToken token, User currentUser) {
            Assert.fail("Test was a success. Consumption should fail.");
            signal.countDown();
          }

          @Override
          public void onError(Throwable t) {
            Assert.fail(); // Test should fail here.
            signal.countDown();
          }
        });
      }
    });
    assertTrue(signal.await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    Assert.assertTrue("Signal", signal.getCount() == 0);
  }
  ... more tests
}
```

I expect this test to fail, and while debugging, I see that `Assert.fail();` indeed fails. However, all the other tests in the class will NOT be run because I get the following:

```
Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'junit.framework.AssertionFailedError''. Check device logcat for details
```

How can I make this test fail but continue on the other tests? Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

I've also tried to use `getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync()` instead of `runTestOnUiThread()` to no avail...

Comment: Because the Assert.Fail() throws an exception and it baloons up to the test http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/01/31/java-handling-a-runtimeexception-in-a-runnable/